# how to get extension attributes in Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface?

Tags: magento2, attributes, extensions

Created a custom module for products with some filters. return it by Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface. how do I include extension attributes in this?

Answer (score 0):

create the **extension_attributes.xml** file at below path,

path : **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc**,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="[Attribute_code]" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
   
</config>
```